# Trying to not use wood in basement walls

Tags: basement, framing

I am doing a basement project and trying to keep wood/organic products out of the wall to prevent potential wood rot or mold. There are metal studs in place, but these are not good for mounting trim work or cabinets. I am curious if composite decking, mounted horizontally between the studs, would be effective as a way to mount cabinets and trim once the drywall has been installed?  Is there any better technique?

Comment: The paper in drywall will feed mold.  Even products marketed to "resist" or "prevent" mold growth aren't 100% effective in all situations (Hurricanes Irene and Sandy taught this to a lot of people...even those with minor water infiltration).

Comment: I used https://insofast.com/ on my basement remodel and it was absolutely great

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason wood shouldn't suffice. That is the way most basements are built, mold would only be an issue if the is bad drainage and water buildup. But even without that you might just use a dehumidifier to reduce dampness in the basement.

Answer (score 1):

If we are framing a basement that can get water we use pressure treated lumber.  All of the problems that you describe are of almost not chance with PT wood.  Not really sure what you are going with the actual wall though because that will mold first by far if drywall.

Comment: Using PT wood inside is a code violation in most, if not all, of the U.S. because of the carcinogenic chemicals used to treat it.

Comment: @JamesOlson - Absolutely incorrect.  It has been 10+ years since any PT wood has been treated with carcinogenic chemicals.  Read up on this.  Also  almost all areas I have done basements require PT for baseplate framing near walls.   And if you watch Mike Holmes he uses PT almost all of the time in basements (colored a pretty blue or purple for TV).

Comment: Right. Furthermore, CCA [was never really a concern in the first place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromated_copper_arsenate#Limitation_of_human_exposure), and its disuse was largely a business decision after unfounded fears reduced marketability of lumber treated with CCA.

Comment: @isherwood - There was actually some real concern.  Not with framing walls but people were using PT lumber for things like picnic tables.  This is what pushed all the PT negativity.  A simple label saying don't use for any surfaces for eating or prep would have probably worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use backing plate for metal studs, but they could be difficult to find for diyer. Check clarkdietriech website for details:

http://www.clarkdietrich.com/products/backing-systems/backing-plate

You might also order similar thing from custom sheet metal shop.